Spooky behaviour of JAX
This is a follow-up to my previous question. I am implementing a Parameterized Quantum Circuit as a Quantum Neural Network, where the optimization loop is jitted. Although there's no error, everything is working fine, I find a very unusual behavior in terms of execution times.
Check out the code below:
Setting - 1
import pennylane as qml
from pennylane import numpy as np
import jax
from jax import numpy as jnp
import optax
from itertools import combinations
from sklearn.datasets import load_digits
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import log_loss
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")
np.random.seed(42)
import time

# Load the digits dataset with features (X_digits) and labels (y_digits)
X_digits, y_digits = load_digits(return_X_y=True)

# Create a boolean mask to filter out only the samples where the label is 2 or 6
filter_mask = np.isin(y_digits, [2, 6])

# Apply the filter mask to the features and labels to keep only the selected digits
X_digits = X_digits[filter_mask]
y_digits = y_digits[filter_mask]

# Split the filtered dataset into training and testing sets with 10% of data reserved for testing
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
    X_digits, y_digits, test_size=0.1, random_state=42
)

# Normalize the pixel values in the training and testing data
# Convert each image from a 1D array to an 8x8 2D array, normalize pixel values, and scale them
X_train = np.array([thing.reshape([8, 8]) / 16 * 2 * np.pi for thing in X_train])
X_test = np.array([thing.reshape([8, 8]) / 16 * 2 * np.pi for thing in X_test])

# Adjust the labels to be centered around 0 and scaled to be in the range -1 to 1
# The original labels (2 and 6) are mapped to -1 and 1 respectively
y_train = (y_train - 4) / 2
y_test = (y_test - 4) / 2


def feature_map(features):
    # Apply Hadamard gates to all qubits to create an equal superposition state
    for i in range(len(features[0])):
        qml.Hadamard(i)

    # Apply angle embeddings based on the feature values
    for i in range(len(features)):
        # For odd-indexed features, use Z-rotation in the angle embedding
        if i % 2:
            qml.AngleEmbedding(features=features[i], wires=range(8), rotation="Z")
        # For even-indexed features, use X-rotation in the angle embedding
        else:
            qml.AngleEmbedding(features=features[i], wires=range(8), rotation="X")

# Define the ansatz (quantum circuit ansatz) for parameterized quantum operations
def ansatz(params):
    # Apply RY rotations with the first set of parameters
    for i in range(8):
        qml.RY(params[i], wires=i)

    # Apply CNOT gates with adjacent qubits (cyclically connected) to create entanglement
    for i in range(8):
        qml.CNOT(wires=[(i - 1) % 8, (i) % 8])

    # Apply RY rotations with the second set of parameters
    for i in range(8):
        qml.RY(params[i + 8], wires=i)

    # Apply CNOT gates with qubits in reverse order (cyclically connected)
    # to create additional entanglement
    for i in range(8):
        qml.CNOT(wires=[(8 - 2 - i) % 8, (8 - i - 1) % 8])



dev = qml.device("default.qubit", wires=8)


@qml.qnode(dev)
def circuit(params, features):
    feature_map(features)
    ansatz(params)
    return qml.expval(qml.PauliZ(0))


def variational_classifier(weights, bias, x):
    return circuit(weights, x) + bias


def square_loss(labels, predictions):
    return np.mean((labels - qml.math.stack(predictions)) ** 2)


def accuracy(labels, predictions):
    acc = sum([np.sign(l) == np.sign(p) for l, p in zip(labels, predictions)])
    acc = acc / len(labels)
    return acc


def cost(params, X, Y):
    predictions = [variational_classifier(params["weights"], params["bias"], x) for x in X]
    return square_loss(Y, predictions)


def acc(params, X, Y):
    predictions = [variational_classifier(params["weights"], params["bias"], x) for x in X]
    return accuracy(Y, predictions)


np.random.seed(0)
weights = 0.01 * np.random.randn(16)
bias = jnp.array(0.0)
params = {"weights": weights, "bias": bias}
opt = optax.adam(0.05)
batch_size = 7
num_batch = X_train.shape[0] // batch_size
opt_state = opt.init(params)
X_batched = X_train.reshape([-1, batch_size, 8, 8])
y_batched = y_train.reshape([-1, batch_size])


@jax.jit
def update_step_jit(i, args):
    params, opt_state, data, targets, X_test, y_test, X_train, y_train, batch_no, print_training = args
    _data = data[batch_no % num_batch]
    _targets = targets[batch_no % num_batch]
    train_loss, grads = jax.value_and_grad(cost)(params, _data, _targets)
    updates, opt_state = opt.update(grads, opt_state)
    test_loss, grads = jax.value_and_grad(cost)(params, X_test, y_test)
    params = optax.apply_updates(params, updates)

    # Print training loss every step if print_training is True
    def print_fn():
        jax.debug.print("Step: {i}, Train Loss: {train_loss}", i=i, train_loss=train_loss)
        jax.debug.print("Step: {i}, Test Loss: {test_loss}", i=i, test_loss=test_loss)

    jax.lax.cond((jnp.mod(i, 1) == 0) & print_training, print_fn, lambda: None)
    return (params, opt_state, data, targets, X_test, y_test, X_train, y_train, batch_no + 1, print_training)


@jax.jit
def optimization_jit(params, data, targets, X_test, y_test, X_train, y_train, print_training = True):
    opt_state = opt.init(params)
    args = (params, opt_state, data, targets, X_test, y_test, X_train, y_train, 0, print_training)
    (params, _, _, _, _, _, _, _, _, _) = jax.lax.fori_loop(0, 1, update_step_jit, args)
    return params


start_time = time.time()
params = optimization_jit(params, X_batched, y_batched, X_test, y_test, X_train, y_train)
print("Training Done! \nTime taken:",time.time() - start_time)

start_time = time.time()
var_train_acc = acc(params, X_train, y_train)
print("Training accuracy: ", var_train_acc)
print("Time taken:",time.time() - start_time)

start_time = time.time()
var_test_acc = acc(params, X_test, y_test)
print("Testing accuracy: ", var_test_acc)
print("Time taken:",time.time() - start_time)

Notice that it is running the jax.lax.fori_loop just 1 time.
For reproducibility, I verified it by running 3 times, and the outputs are as follows,
Output of first run:
Training Done! 
Time taken: 66.26599097251892
Step: 0, Train Loss: 1.015419602394104
Step: 0, Test Loss: 1.0022056102752686
Training accuracy:  0.5031055900621118
Time taken: 14.183394193649292
Testing accuracy:  0.5277777777777778
Time taken: 1.552431344985962

Output of second run:
Training Done! 
Time taken: 62.8515682220459
Step: 0, Train Loss: 1.015419602394104
Step: 0, Test Loss: 1.0022056102752686
Training accuracy:  0.5031055900621118
Time taken: 13.549866199493408
Testing accuracy:  0.5277777777777778
Time taken: 1.5097148418426514

Output of third run:
Training Done! 
Time taken: 63.35235905647278
Step: 0, Train Loss: 1.015419602394104
Step: 0, Test Loss: 1.0022056102752686
Training accuracy:  0.5031055900621118
Time taken: 13.52238941192627
Testing accuracy:  0.5277777777777778
Time taken: 1.5074975490570068

Setting - 2
So, then I ran it changing the jax.lax.fori_loop to run 10 times as
    (params, _, _, _, _, _, _, _, _, _) = jax.lax.fori_loop(0, 10, update_step_jit, args)

Surprisingly, the execution time reduces quite significantly, and the outputs are:
First Run:
Training Done! 
Time taken: 49.8694589138031
Step: 0, Train Loss: 1.015419602394104
Step: 0, Test Loss: 1.0022056102752686
Step: 1, Train Loss: 0.934578537940979
Step: 1, Test Loss: 0.9935969114303589
Step: 2, Train Loss: 0.982826828956604
Step: 2, Test Loss: 1.004722237586975
Step: 3, Train Loss: 0.982965350151062
Step: 3, Test Loss: 1.0281261205673218
Step: 4, Train Loss: 1.1700845956802368
Step: 4, Test Loss: 1.0455362796783447
Step: 5, Train Loss: 1.3356019258499146
Step: 5, Test Loss: 1.0411475896835327
Step: 6, Train Loss: 1.2408322095870972
Step: 6, Test Loss: 1.0204349756240845
Step: 7, Train Loss: 0.7292405366897583
Step: 7, Test Loss: 0.9959328770637512
Step: 8, Train Loss: 1.1697252988815308
Step: 8, Test Loss: 0.9822244644165039
Step: 9, Train Loss: 1.015731692314148
Step: 9, Test Loss: 0.9667297005653381
Training accuracy:  0.5217391304347826
Time taken: 13.903431177139282
Testing accuracy:  0.5555555555555556
Time taken: 1.537736177444458

Second run:
Training Done! 
Time taken: 56.34339928627014
Step: 0, Train Loss: 1.015419602394104
Step: 0, Test Loss: 1.0022056102752686
Step: 1, Train Loss: 0.934578537940979
Step: 1, Test Loss: 0.9935969114303589
Step: 2, Train Loss: 0.982826828956604
Step: 2, Test Loss: 1.004722237586975
Step: 3, Train Loss: 0.982965350151062
Step: 3, Test Loss: 1.0281261205673218
Step: 4, Train Loss: 1.1700845956802368
Step: 4, Test Loss: 1.0455362796783447
Step: 5, Train Loss: 1.3356019258499146
Step: 5, Test Loss: 1.0411475896835327
Step: 6, Train Loss: 1.2408322095870972
Step: 6, Test Loss: 1.0204349756240845
Step: 7, Train Loss: 0.7292405366897583
Step: 7, Test Loss: 0.9959328770637512
Step: 8, Train Loss: 1.1697252988815308
Step: 8, Test Loss: 0.9822244644165039
Step: 9, Train Loss: 1.015731692314148
Step: 9, Test Loss: 0.9667297005653381
Training accuracy:  0.5217391304347826
Time taken: 13.298640727996826
Testing accuracy:  0.5555555555555556
Time taken: 1.4631397724151611

Third run:
Training Done! 
Time taken: 53.01019215583801
Step: 0, Train Loss: 1.015419602394104
Step: 0, Test Loss: 1.0022056102752686
Step: 1, Train Loss: 0.934578537940979
Step: 1, Test Loss: 0.9935969114303589
Step: 2, Train Loss: 0.982826828956604
Step: 2, Test Loss: 1.004722237586975
Step: 3, Train Loss: 0.982965350151062
Step: 3, Test Loss: 1.0281261205673218
Step: 4, Train Loss: 1.1700845956802368
Step: 4, Test Loss: 1.0455362796783447
Step: 5, Train Loss: 1.3356019258499146
Step: 5, Test Loss: 1.0411475896835327
Step: 6, Train Loss: 1.2408322095870972
Step: 6, Test Loss: 1.0204349756240845
Step: 7, Train Loss: 0.7292405366897583
Step: 7, Test Loss: 0.9959328770637512
Step: 8, Train Loss: 1.1697252988815308
Step: 8, Test Loss: 0.9822244644165039
Step: 9, Train Loss: 1.015731692314148
Step: 9, Test Loss: 0.9667297005653381
Training accuracy:  0.5217391304347826
Time taken: 13.152780055999756
Testing accuracy:  0.5555555555555556
Time taken: 1.4448845386505127

Setting - 3
Furthermore, I thought of reducing the logging, and wanted to calculate and log the test_loss  every 5th step, by updating the code to:
@jax.jit
def update_step_jit(i, args):
    params, opt_state, data, targets, X_test, y_test, X_train, y_train, batch_no, print_training = args
    _data = data[batch_no % num_batch]
    _targets = targets[batch_no % num_batch]
    train_loss, grads = jax.value_and_grad(cost)(params, _data, _targets)
    updates, opt_state = opt.update(grads, opt_state)
    # train_accuracy, grads = jax.value_and_grad(acc)(params, X_train, y_train)
    # test_accuracy, grads = jax.value_and_grad(acc)(params, X_test, y_test)
    params = optax.apply_updates(params, updates)

    # Print training loss every 5 steps if print_training is True
    def print_fn():
        test_loss, grads = jax.value_and_grad(cost)(params, X_test, y_test)
        jax.debug.print("Step: {i}, Train Loss: {train_loss}", i=i, train_loss=train_loss)
        # jax.debug.print("Step: {i}, Train Accuracy: {train_accuracy}", i=i, train_accuracy=train_accuracy)
        jax.debug.print("Step: {i}, Test Loss: {test_loss}", i=i, test_loss=test_loss)
        # jax.debug.print("Step: {i}, Test Accuracy: {test_accuracy}", i=i, test_accuracy=test_accuracy)

    jax.lax.cond((jnp.mod(i, 5) == 0) & print_training, print_fn, lambda: None)
    return (params, opt_state, data, targets, X_test, y_test, X_train, y_train, batch_no + 1, print_training)


@jax.jit
def optimization_jit(params, data, targets, X_test, y_test, X_train, y_train, print_training = True):
    opt_state = opt.init(params)
    args = (params, opt_state, data, targets, X_test, y_test, X_train, y_train, 0, print_training)
    (params, _, _, _, _, _, _, _, _, _) = jax.lax.fori_loop(0, 10, update_step_jit, args)
    return params


I though calling the print_fn fewer times would have resulted in even lesser runtime but no, the outputs were:
First Run:
Training Done! 
Time taken: 75.2902774810791
Step: 0, Train Loss: 1.015419602394104
Step: 0, Test Loss: 0.9935969114303589
Step: 5, Train Loss: 1.3356019258499146
Step: 5, Test Loss: 1.0204349756240845
Training accuracy:  0.5217391304347826
Time taken: 13.591582536697388
Testing accuracy:  0.5555555555555556
Time taken: 1.6048238277435303

Second run:
Training Done! 
Time taken: 86.21267819404602
Step: 0, Train Loss: 1.015419602394104
Step: 0, Test Loss: 0.9935969114303589
Step: 5, Train Loss: 1.3356019258499146
Step: 5, Test Loss: 1.0204349756240845
Training accuracy:  0.5217391304347826
Time taken: 13.666489601135254
Testing accuracy:  0.5555555555555556
Time taken: 1.5537452697753906

Third run:
Training Done! 
Time taken: 90.7916328907013
Step: 0, Train Loss: 1.015419602394104
Step: 0, Test Loss: 0.9935969114303589
Step: 5, Train Loss: 1.3356019258499146
Step: 5, Test Loss: 1.0204349756240845
Training accuracy:  0.5217391304347826
Time taken: 13.21641230583191
Testing accuracy:  0.5555555555555556
Time taken: 1.5349321365356445

The runtimes for the different settings can be plotted as:

My questions are:

Why is Setting - 1, where the optimization loop is run only once, consistently taking more time than Setting - 2, where the optimization loop is run 10 times?
Why is Setting - 3, where the print_fn function in the optimization loop is called every 5th optimization step, consistently taking more time than Setting - 2, where the print_fn is being called on every iteration?


The compiler works in mysterious ways!
I suspect the difference here is that in the case of a length-1 fori_loop, the compiler optimizes-away the scan; for example:
$ print(jax.jit(lambda x: jax.lax.fori_loop(0, 1, lambda i, x: x * 2, x)).lower(1.0).compile().as_text())
HloModule jit__lambda_, is_scheduled=true, entry_computation_layout={(f32[])->f32[]}, allow_spmd_sharding_propagation_to_parameters={true}, allow_spmd_sharding_propagation_to_output={true}

ENTRY %main.25 (Arg_0.1: f32[]) -> f32[] {
  %Arg_0.1 = f32[] parameter(0), metadata={op_name="x"}
  %constant.3 = f32[] constant(2)
  ROOT %multiply.1 = f32[] multiply(f32[] %Arg_0.1, f32[] %constant.3), metadata={op_name="jit(<lambda>)/jit(main)/while/body/mul" source_file="<ipython-input-10-f67509edfb4c>" source_line=1}
}

But with a non-trivial for loop, the scan is not optimized away:
$ print(jax.jit(lambda x: jax.lax.fori_loop(0, 10, lambda i, x: x * 2, x)).lower(1.0).compile().as_text())
HloModule jit__lambda_, is_scheduled=true, entry_computation_layout={(f32[])->f32[]}, allow_spmd_sharding_propagation_to_parameters={true}, allow_spmd_sharding_propagation_to_output={true}

%region_0.8 (arg_tuple.9: (s32[], f32[])) -> (s32[], f32[]) {
  %constant.12 = s32[] constant(1)
  %arg_tuple.9 = (s32[], f32[]) parameter(0)
  %get-tuple-element.2 = s32[] get-tuple-element((s32[], f32[]) %arg_tuple.9), index=0
  %add.14 = s32[] add(s32[] %get-tuple-element.2, s32[] %constant.12), metadata={op_name="jit(<lambda>)/jit(main)/while/body/add" source_file="<ipython-input-11-d89e1a4ad053>" source_line=1}
  %constant.0 = f32[] constant(2)
  %get-tuple-element.3 = f32[] get-tuple-element((s32[], f32[]) %arg_tuple.9), index=1
  %multiply.0 = f32[] multiply(f32[] %get-tuple-element.3, f32[] %constant.0), metadata={op_name="jit(<lambda>)/jit(main)/while/body/mul" source_file="<ipython-input-11-d89e1a4ad053>" source_line=1}
  ROOT %tuple.2 = (s32[], f32[]) tuple(s32[] %add.14, f32[] %multiply.0)
}

%region_1.16 (arg_tuple.17: (s32[], f32[])) -> pred[] {
  %constant.20 = s32[] constant(10)
  %arg_tuple.17 = (s32[], f32[]) parameter(0)
  %get-tuple-element.18 = s32[] get-tuple-element((s32[], f32[]) %arg_tuple.17), index=0
  ROOT %compare.21 = pred[] compare(s32[] %get-tuple-element.18, s32[] %constant.20), direction=LT, metadata={op_name="jit(<lambda>)/jit(main)/while/cond/lt" source_file="<ipython-input-11-d89e1a4ad053>" source_line=1}
}

ENTRY %main.25 (Arg_0.1: f32[]) -> f32[] {
  %Arg_0.1 = f32[] parameter(0), metadata={op_name="x"}
  %copy.6 = f32[] copy(f32[] %Arg_0.1)
  %constant.2 = s32[] constant(0)
  %copy.7 = s32[] copy(s32[] %constant.2)
  %tuple = (s32[], f32[]) tuple(s32[] %copy.7, f32[] %copy.6)
  %while.22 = (s32[], f32[]) while((s32[], f32[]) %tuple), condition=%region_1.16, body=%region_0.8, metadata={op_name="jit(<lambda>)/jit(main)/while" source_file="<ipython-input-11-d89e1a4ad053>" source_line=1}, backend_config={"known_trip_count":{"n":"10"}}
  ROOT %get-tuple-element.24 = f32[] get-tuple-element((s32[], f32[]) %while.22), index=1, metadata={op_name="jit(<lambda>)/jit(main)/while" source_file="<ipython-input-11-d89e1a4ad053>" source_line=1}
}

The result of this, even for the simple function here, is that the compiler produces some fusions in the second case that it does not in the first; in your case it's probably the case that those fusions lead to faster execution.
A perfect compiler would never make a decision like this that leads to slower execution, but no compiler is perfect. If you wish, you could report this at https://github.com/openxla/xla, but you'd probably want to try for a far more minimized reproduction before doing so.
